# Why does negation happen last in an assignment expression in PHP?

Tags: php

The negation operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator, why is it lower in an expression?

e.g.

```
if (!$var = getVar()) {
```

In the previous expression the assignment happens first, the negation later. Shouldn't the negation be first, then the assignment?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The left hand side of `=` [has to be a `variable`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#778). `$var` is a `variable`, whereas `!$var` is not (it's an `expr_without_variable`).

Thus PHP parses the expression in the only possible way, namely as `!($var = getVar())`. Precedence never comes to play here.

An example of where the the precedence of `=` is relevant is this:

```
$a = $b || $c // ==> $a = ($b || $c), because || has higher precedence than =
$a = $b or $c // ==> ($a = $b) or $c, because or has lower precedence than =
```

Comment: While the accepted answer is technically correct, this answer is more thorough and easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, if it were possible I'd delete my answer in favour of this one.

Comment: You can flag it for moderator attention and explain if you want. That said, I don't think your answer is bad (or be deleted). This one is just better. :)

Comment: @NikiC Could you update the link to `zend_language_parser.y`? Because it's the trunk the content of line 738 changes. Bunch about `traits` there now. Thanks

Comment: @NikiC Perfect. I still don't get it =) but thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

**In short, assignments will always have precedence over their left part**
(as it would result in a parse error in the contrary case).

```
 <?php
 $b=12 + $a = 5 + 6;
 echo "$a $b\n";
 --> 11 23

 $b=(12 + $a) = (5 + 6);
 echo "$a $b\n";
 --> Parse error
```

The PHP documentation has now a note concerning this question: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php
(i guessed it was added after your question)

> Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in which case the return value of foo() is put into $a

Comment: It's had the note for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Negotiation operator needs to check a single value at the next, so if you give like this

> !$var =
>   getVar()

the operator onlyapplicable for the next variable so !$var is will seperated. so only we need to give

> !($var =
>   getVar())

Comment: This is not correct. See the documentation note and the .y grammar rules and the other answers. I show the applied productions here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32672872/2864740 That is, PHP's grammar is just a bit different then some other languages.