# PHP conditional assignment

Tags: php, operator-precedence

Found an interesting piece of code in Symfony core

```
if ('' !== $host = $route->getHost()) {
    ...
}
```

The precedence of !== is higher than the = but how does it work logically? The first part is clear but the rest?

I've created a little sample but it's still not clear: [sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/205f7fa43e9f348b8669074c94d8fc182e28fd6a)

Comment: Do it the save way `if ('' !== ($host = $route->getHost())) {`

Comment: avoid problem using parenthesis ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS vs PHP: assignment operator precedence when used with logical-or](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672016/js-vs-php-assignment-operator-precedence-when-used-with-logical-or)

Comment: Look at this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/392fb443d315f2fe5e032a8e44c19c8fe3acdc5d  maybe you get wired more or get it fully ;-) But for humanreadable and savety do it in the save way. By thw way this `$host = $route->getHost()` can be done a line before :-)

Comment: I just don't get how can the $host = $route->getHost() part be executed first as the precedence is lower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is: The left hand side of an assignment has to be an variable! The only possible way to achieve this in your example is to evaluate the assignment first - which is what php actually does.

Adding parenthesis makes clear, what happens

```
'' !== $host = $route->getHost()
// is equal to
'' !== ($host = $route->getHost())
// the other way wouldn't work
// ('' != $host) = $route->getHost()
```

So the condition is true, if the return value of `$route->getHost()` is an non empty string and in each case, the return value is assigned to `$host`.

In addition, you could have a look a the [grammer](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP-5.6/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#778) of PHP

```
...
variable '=' expr |
variable '=' '&' variable |
variable '=' '&' T_NEW class_name_reference | ...
```

If you read the operator [precendence manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) page carefully, you would see this notice

> Although = has a lower precedence than most other operators, PHP will
>   still allow expressions similar to the following: if (!$a = foo()), in
>   which case the return value of foo() is put into $a.

Comment: same reason wordpress coding standards use [yoda conditions](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions)

Comment: Thank you - that was my guess but could not find it in the docs